# How apache.commons.lang3 is added to Jhipster external libraries without adding to pom.xml file?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, jhipster

I see apache.commons.lang3 library used in Jhipster's source but I cannot find its maven dependency inside pom.xml file. There are other dependencies like that as well and I want to know how they were added? or Is  their corresponding Jar file is added while installing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, they come from `jhipster-dependencies` import which is a [BOM](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#bill-of-materials-bom-poms). This is also used by Spring Boot.

You can check with `mvnw dependency:tree`